# Layout for a Matrix in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am making a Matrix Calculator. And i am Confused with which Layout to Use and How to Modify it Dynamically.
Below are my Requirements :

1. I should be able to put values to it, Dynamically from a 2D FLOAT variable
2. It should be able able to change its size (Row and Column) Dynamically
3. I should be able to Extract all values from it to a float 2D variable.

Comment: You can have a look at GridLayout. But I'm not sure if GridLayout supports your requirement 2, you might need to write your own Views to do that.

Comment: Then How do i write my own View??

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html
But IMHO you should try GridLayout first.

Comment: Okay thank but just post me a code on how to do this. Suppose i am passing following values through intent extras 1. Row number, 2. Column Number, 3. A 2D integer array with same number of rows and cols as mentioned. Now this activity creates should create a grid layout with Row and Column as passed. and Every child of this grid will be a edit text, which will be filled with the passed integer array value... Please provide a Code, would be better.